# Error al querer instalar packages, npm

Tags: nodejs, npm, plugin, packages

Saludos estimados usuarios de stackoverflow.

Estaba intentando instalar ionic por medio de la consola, [con ayuda de la documentación oficial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli).

Sin embargo al ejecutar el comando: `npm install -g ionic`, aparece el proceso normal de descarga de paquete durante un momento y luego aparece el siguiente error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"eslint-plugin-node"'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\[usuario]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\[nombre archivo].log

Cuando apareció este error, lo busque en la web claro, pero por lo menos yo no encontré nada que lo solucionara, pero como medida desesperada decidí desinstalar `node.js` y volverlo a instalar, e incluso ahora, sigue apareciendo el error.

Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando windows 10, con `node.js v10.15.13` y `npm 6.4.1`

**Intente ejecutar otros comandos de npm como:** **`npm install -g @vue/cli`** **y aparece el mismo error.**
también ejecute el `npm` que menciona en [este](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) y [este otro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-node) enlace y sigue sin funcionar, la verdad ya no se que mas hacer.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, enserio.

Comment: Ya intentaste correr este comando? `npm cache clean --force`. Según leo en algunas páginas parece ser que debido a una mala conexión a internet pueden corromperse unos archivos, y por eso te arroja ese error. Si aún así no te funciona, entonces intenta volver a desinstalar el node, pero esta vez asegúrate de borrar el `package.json` global y luego si volver a instalarlo

Comment: el `package.json` donde se encuentra exactamente?

Comment: Error del comentario, en realidad era la carpeta de `node-modules` a lo que me refería, no al `package.json` ese no debe existir. Normalmente se guardan en las carpetas raiz de acuerdo al sistema operativo y pueden estar ocultas. Ya de acuerdo a tu sistema te invito a que investigues y averigües

Comment: a node-modules en nodejs? o en donde?

Comment: Bro, si estamos hablando de instalar un archivo global, lo mas probable es que sea el `node_modules` donde se instalan los paquetes globales, para eso tipea el siguiente comando `npm root -g` y la ruta que te salga ve hasta allá y elimina todo lo que hay dentro de la carpeta node_modules, pero no olvides que hay ahí para que puedas volver a instalarlo

Comment: :Lo mencionaba, porque ya había realizado esa acción, y de hecho el `npm cache clean --force` funciono para poder instalar el package de ionic, sin embargo al querer instalar otras cosas como @vue/cli, sigue apareciendo errores, ya reinstale como dos veces tambien

Comment: Por qué no intentas hacer un downgrade de la versión de Node ya que veo que estás en la mas reciente, e intentas hacer las descargas con otra versión de Node, te recomiendo usar una en LTS

Comment: Entonces eso probare

Comment: Me avisas si te funciona, porque en todo caso, vendría siendo un issue